Как получить изображение из формы html и отправить их с остальными данными в бд?
Как получить изображение из формы html и отправить их с остальными данными в бд? Снизу прикрепил код, у меня несколько input если я убираю input с изображением и соответственно его подключение к бд, то все срабатывает и данные отправляются в бд, а если input с изображением остается в форме и я его подключаю, то никакая информация не попадает в бд.
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "1234";
$database = "BorkiFestival_site";

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['description_2']) && isset($_POST['card_img']) && isset($_POST['img']) && isset($_POST['description'])){
//переменные с формы
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$description = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description']));
$description_2 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['description_2']));


$tmp_dir = '/var/www/uploads/'; // путь к временной директории из настроек php.ini
$tmp_file = $tmp_dir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']); // путь к временному файлу
$img = $tmp_file;
$tmp_dir = '/var/www/uploads/'; // путь к временной директории из настроек php.ini
$tmp_file = $tmp_dir . basename($_FILES['card_img']['name']); // путь к временному файлу
$card_img = $tmp_file;

$arr = [
    'января',
    'февраля',
    'марта',
    'апреля',
    'мая',
    'июня',
    'июля',
    'августа',
    'сентября',
    'октября',
    'ноября',
    'декабря'
    ];
    $month = date('n')-1;

    $date = date("d $arr[$month] Y");

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

$dbtable = 'cards';

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbtable." (name, description, description_2, date, card_img, img) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$description_2', '$date', '$card_img', '$img')";

//внесём данные с формы в БД
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

mysqli_close($link);
header('location: news-admin.php');
}
?>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="news-admin.php" method="POST" id="form-admin" class="form__admin form__admin_program">
        <h2 class="title-footer margin-bottom-40px">
            Добавьте новость
        </h2>
        <div class="form__group">
        <input type="text" class="form__input form_login" placeholder="Введите название" name="name" id="name" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
        <textarea type="text" class="form__input form__input_big form_password" placeholder="Введите первую часть статьи" id="description" name="description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
        <textarea type="text" class="form__input form__input_big form_password" placeholder="Введите вторую часть статьи" id="description_2" name="description_2" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
        <input type="file" class="form__input form_login" name="card_img"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
        <input type="file" class="form__input form_login" name="img"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form__groop">
          <input type="submit" placeholder="Отправить" class="btn_animated btn-form margin-bottom-20px">
        </div>
      </form>


Миллиард уже существует туториалов как загрузить файл с помощью php.

ну тут только можно посоветовать включить отображение ошибок - раз, сделать отладку кода - два
